# (Dynamic) Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

My problem is the following. Let $t\in[0,1]$, let $u(t)\in[0,1]$ be the control funciton, and $a\in[\underline{a},\overline{a}]$ is a parameter. I know that the solution to the problem
$$
\int_0^1 L(u,a,t) dt \rightarrow \max_{u\in[0,1]}
$$
where $L$ is a `nice' (continuously differentiable, etc.) function, takes the following form: $u(t)=0$ for $t<t_a$ and $u(t)=1$ for $t\geq t_a$. So, it is a bang-bang solution with switching time depending on parameter $a$.

Now, the quesiton I have: is it true, that solution to
$$
\int_{\underline{a}}^{\overline{a}}\left(\int_0^1 L(u,a,t) dt\right)f(a)da \rightarrow \max_{u\in[0,1]}
$$
where $f(a)>0$ -- a continuous (density) funciton, takes the same form with a unique switching point?

Comment: In your first display, what does the $\rightarrow$ refer to, and what does the maximum over an unspecified function "$\max_{u\in[0,1]}$" mean?

Comment: $u$ is a control variable, between 0 and 1, and the arrow means maximizing it. That is, whenever the integral is maximized, $u$ is a step function, jumping from 0 to 1 at some point. The question is whether this implies that the same is true for an "average".

Comment: So $u^*(t, a) = \arg\max_{u\in PC([0,1])} \int_0^1 L(u, a, t) dt$, where $PC([0,1])$ is the set of piecewise continuous functions on $[0,1]$, and $u^*$ is known to be a bang-bang solution?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It is bang-bang, always jumps up, but at different points, depending on $a$.